# Has Chrome browser broken dynamic script loading?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dynamic, load

This isn't my code, I'm just troubleshooting it. Some code that has been working for over a year has now stopped working in Chrome (12.0.742.122), but works in the other "big" browsers (including fellow WebKit stablemate Safari (5.0.5)). By "not working anymore" I mean that although the script file does load, it doesn't execute. The kind of behaviour you'd expect if loading a script into innerHTML or writing it *into* a div, but neither of which things are being done. The commented-out lines below were all failed attempts at getting it working, the first of those being the original code that had worked up until recently.

```
<div id="abc"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var d=document.getElementById("abc");
var s=document.createElement('SCRIPT');
if(s){s.src=script_path;}
//if(d)d.appendChild(s);        //original line that still works in all other browsers
//if(d)d.parentNode.appendChild(s);
//if(d)d.parentNode.insertBefore(s,d);
//if(d)d.parentNode.insertBefore(s,d.nextSibling);
document.body.appendChild(s);   //this works, script executes
</script>
```

What is wanted from this code above, is that the script is a child of the div. Presumably they want to be able to remove that child and have all script be removed at the same time (I'm not sure of their motivation).

Comment: `document.createElement('SCRIPT')` try lower-case 'script'

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, I've tried that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered what the problem was, largely thanks to Martin Bieder's back and forth and introducing me to jsfiddle.net with his working example.

The issue was actually the test page and what you'd think would be a fairly harmless error they made in creating it. The div and all of the code will be represented below simply as ######, as it's not even relevant to the problem. It's actually a HTML problem. Chrome 12 isn't happy if you don't match up your closing tags properly. I really can't believe that it has an effect on the execution on script files, but it does. I've tried many many times in the last 10 minutes with the HTML tags right and wrong and unbelievably this really is the problem.

```
<font><center><b>
##########
</b></font></center>
```

You see how the font and center closing tags are the wrong way around, and that's enough to confuse Chrome sufficiently that it won't execute any dynamic script being added within those tags. Bizarre. I can't recreate this on jsfiddle, probably due to the nature of the site runs the html/js that you put onto it (using onload for example).

Comment: As a total web novice, a possible reason I can think of for that behaviour might be that Chrome considers scripts to be owned by their enclosing HTML elements, and if the enclosing element fails to render then it makes no sense to execute its script. In fact, that could go for any tags inside other failing tags.

Comment: Yeah, in that mismatched set of tags, I imagine something along the lines of <font> "ok, I'm waiting for a close font now", <center> "stack that I'm waiting for a close font because I'm now waiting for a close center". Then <b> comes and gets matched, and it pops the state "waiting for a close center tag". At that point, it encounters a close font tag and thinks "what's that doing here, I'm not waiting for one of these, ignore it". Then comes the close center it's waiting for, and it pops it's original "waiting for font close" state, and the close font never arrives, so no script execution.

Answer (score 1):

No it works. Google Analytics uses is, too.

```
var ga=document.createElement('script');
ga.type='text/javascript';
ga.async=true;
ga.src='http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where you place the script.

Comment: It might not matter to you, and it's never mattered to me either, but the owners of this code want the script to be either a sibling of the div, or a child of the div. I've already figured out my primary response to them, just attach the script to the document.body, as shown in the last line of my code snippet above, but I'm seeking out a way to link it to the div, as they want to. If that can't be done, then I'll definitely tell them to attach to the body (or insert after the last script, as your code snippet does).

Comment: The script will be executed the same way. It really doesn't matter. But you can use `document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(script)` if you want to.

Comment: I know it normally doesn't matter, the main crux of this post though, is that suddenly on Chrome it *does* matter. Maybe it was their most recent release.

Comment: WOW. That's all I can say. Holy Bejeezus Chrome is overly sensitive. I spent the last 40 mins (since your last post Martin) trying to wrap my head around why your code was working, yet this test page I was debugging wasn't working. You won't believe how stupid the solution was. I'm going to try and answer my own question below (if I'm allowed to, I tried once before on another question and it wouldn't let me).

Comment: Well, in 6 hours I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set to `async` the script element?

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.async = 'async';
```

Comment: I've tried that, it makes things worse rather than better. Instead of loading the script but not executing, by having the async set like that, the file doesn't even load at all.

Comment: Seems that your only solution is to append the script element where it should be appended (aka _head_), and in some way link the element you are supposed to append the script to and the script element. Something similar to jQuery's data implementation.

Answer (score -2):

It is all about 3 things.. Organization, Optimization, and debugging.

1)properly scoping your tags makes things easier to read. 
2)properly organizing your code makes it easier to parse which means parsers can be faster and more efficient.
3)alot of the debug tools we use rely on this organization in order to display things like collapsible tags and present a more visual scoping